# install perception pcl

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-1.7, perception-pcl, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

I'm trying to install the package here [perception_pcl](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl.git) to use the object recognition of pcl in ros Groovy. For now I have pcl installed in groovy (pcl 1.6) and I can't figure how to install this repo in my catkin workspace.

I tried cloning it and then catkin_make or cmake then make pcl then catkin_make while isolating the pcl folder but I have tons of dependency error then.

Can someone give me a "how to do it" explanation please ? There is no README so I'm lost ><

I tried follow this [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/62979/how-do-i-use-pcl-17-with-groovy/) as well but there is no cmake_find_ros anymore...

For example I just ran catkin_make after downloading the package and I have that kind of errors :

```
In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl-groovy-unstable-devel/pcl_ros/src/pcl_ros/features/feature.cpp:51:0:
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl-groovy-unstable-devel/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/features/feature.h:43:35: erreur fatale: pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl-groovy-unstable-devel/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp:53:0:
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/perception

_pcl-groovy-unstable-devel/pcl_ros/include/pcl_ros/publisher.h:50:29: erreur fatale: pcl/conversions.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
```

Here is the output of `dkpg -l |grep perception`

```
ros@ros-K56CM:~$ dpkg -l |grep perception
ii  ros-groovy-perception                       1.0.0-s1391975666~precise                           Meta package for perception variant of ROS.
ii  ros-groovy-perception-pcl                   1.0.36-0precise-20131016-0534-+0000                 PCL (Point Cloud Library) ROS interface stack. PCL-ROS is the preferred bridge for 3D applications involving n-D Point Clouds and 3D geometry processing in ROS.
```

Here are my includes in my program :

```
#include <pcl/recognition/cg/hough_3d.h>
#include <pcl/recognition/cg/geometric_consistency.h>
```

And here is the output of catkin_make :

```
ros@ros-K56CM:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make --pkg stalker
Base path: /home/ros/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/ros/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/ros/catkin_ws/build/Tobot/stalker"
####
[ 20%] Built target basic
[ 20%] Built target gui
[ 20%] [ 40%] Building CXX object Tobot/stalker/CMakeFiles/3Dreckon.dir/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/Main.cpp.o
Building CXX object Tobot/stalker/CMakeFiles/3Dreckon.dir/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/CorrespGrouping.cpp.o
In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/stalker/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/Main.hpp:9:0,
                 from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/stalker/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/Main.cpp:1:
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/stalker/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/CorrespGrouping.hpp:8:41: erreur fatale: pcl/recognition/cg/hough_3d.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
In file included from /home/ros/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/stalker/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/CorrespGrouping.cpp:1:0:
/home/ros/catkin_ws/src/Tobot/stalker/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/CorrespGrouping.hpp:8:41: erreur fatale: pcl/recognition/cg/hough_3d.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminée.
make[2]: *** [Tobot/stalker/CMakeFiles/3Dreckon.dir/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/Main.cpp.o] Erreur 1
make[2]: *** Attente des tâches non terminées....
make[2]: *** [Tobot/stalker/CMakeFiles/3Dreckon.dir/include/stalker/reckon_pipeline/CorrespGrouping.cpp.o] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [Tobot/stalker/CMakeFiles/3Dreckon.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

I assume I don't have the library so I tried to install that github package.

Any help will be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154201/install-perception-pcl/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-17**:
Are you on Ubuntu? Have you tried installing perception-pcl from debs?

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-04-17**:
I'm on Ubuntu. I have perception-pcl install from the debs. But when I try to use pcl/recognition/Something.h there is no such file. I'm going to add some information to the question.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-04-18**:
Can you add your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the end I found a way to install on old version of Pcl1.7 trunk that one of my friend had. But thanks for your help !

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petros ADLATUS](https://answers.ros.org/users/99003/petros-adlatus/) on 2022-04-22**:
can you tell me the way please?